# Promises not running in correct order

Tags: node.js, promise, sails.js, q, bluebird

The following is logging in this order: here1 here2 here5 here3 here4. Although, here5 should be last and it's not getting to here6 at all. How can I get here1 to here6 to all run properly in order? I am using Sailsjs and bluebird.

```
//manually wrapping a callback API like Kaiseki
function createKaisekiObject(className, job) {
    console.log('here2');
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        kaiseki.createObject(className, job, function(err, res, body, success) {
            //resolve or reject the promise
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log('here3');
            resolve(body);
        });
    });
}

function saveJob(body) {
    console.log('here4', body);

    return Jobs.create({
        owner: req.user.id,
        jobId: body.objectId
    });
}

function sendResponse(req, res) {
    console.log('here5');

    return function(savedJob) {
        console.log('here6', savedJob, req, res);

        // res.json({
        //  success: true,
        //  message: "Running analysis on game",
        //  jobId: savedJob.jobId
        // });
        //return the job
        return savedJob;
    };
}

module.exports.index = function(req, res) {
    console.log('here1');
    var jobId = uuid.v4();
    var job = {
        owner: req.user.id,
        numOfGames: 1,
        numOfGamesCompleted: 0
    };
    var className = 'jobs';
    //promise
    var createJob = createKaisekiObject(className, job)
    .then(saveJob)
    .then(sendResponse(req, res));

    //when first step is done, do more stuff...
    createJob.then(function(savedJob) {
        //do more stuff here...
        console.log('here6');
    });


};
```

Comment: here5 will never be last.  You're calling `sendResponse()` immediately so thus here5 shows immediately.  `sendResponse()` then returns a function which is passed to the `.then()` handler which won't be called until later when the promise is resolved.  Remember, all `.then()` statements are executed immediately.  Usually, then just store away a function reference that will be called later (so thus don't do much), but when you put `sendResponse(...)` inside of `.then()`, that is executed immediately.

Comment: @jfriend00 How does that explain here6 not logging?

Comment: It doesn't.  I was just commenting on here5.  What does `Jobs.create()` return?  Your code acts like perhaps it is rejecting or throwing and you don't have any reject handlers because no further handlers are executed after you call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I don't believe that Jobs.create returns a promise so you need to wrap it in one if you want to continue chaining.

```
function saveJob(body) {
    console.log('here4', body);

    return function(body) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Jobs.create({
                owner: req.user.id,
                jobId: body.objectId
            }).exec(function(err, job) {
                resolve(job);
            });
        });
    };
}
```

Next make sure that the function that is returned by sendResponse also returns a promise since it is that returned function that will be executed in the chained then block.

```
function sendResponse(req, res) {
    console.log('here5');

    return function(savedJob) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            console.log('here6', savedJob, req, res);
            res.json({
                success: true,
                message: "Running analysis on game",
                jobId: savedJob.jobId
            });
            //return the job
            resolve(savedJob);
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Chaining still works even when a `.then()` handler doesn't return a promise so that part of your answer is not correct.  It just doesn't create yet another promise to wait on and thus continues synchronously.

Comment: Now, your `saveJob` function doesn't return a promise either (but another function). Why?